# How to refresh ListView in previous activity by updating DB in current activity?

Tags: sqlite, listview, android-activity, xamarin.android

I am using Xamarin Android. In the current activity i am having an editing form and on button click event i have an update query in the current activity.

```
private void OnclickSaveDATAButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var CNICCARDNUMBER = Intent.Extras.GetString("NIC");
        var conn = Connection();
        conn.BeginTransaction();
        var hf = conn.Table<mof>();
        var search = hf.Where(x => x.CNICNO == CNICCARDNUMBER).ToList().FirstOrDefault(); //Linq Query
        var Hofid = Convert.ToString(search.HOFID);

        var data = conn.Query<hof>("UPDATE hof SET HOFNAME = ? WHERE HOFID = ?", Name.Text, Hofid);
        conn.Commit();


        if (data!= null)
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this,"Updated Successfully", ToastLength.Short).Show();               

        }
        else
        { 
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Update failed", ToastLength.Short).Show();

        }

    }
```

When I go back to previous activity on back button event

```
    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(SearchingActivity));
        intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
        StartActivity(intent);
    }
```

In the previous activity i am having select query on tab selection event. when i select the tab, I want to refresh the ListView and display the updated data instead  of old one.

```
    else if (CurrentTab.Position == 1)
        {


            Gridd = (ListView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.gridview);
            Gridd.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;


            var CNICCARDNUMBER = Intent.Extras.GetString("cnic");


            var conn = Connection();

            var Hofid = 2;
            data1 = new List<string>();

              var data = conn.Query<combine>("SELECT hof WHERE hof.HOFID=?", Hofid);

            foreach (var values in data)
            {

                data1.Add("CNIC:" + Convert.ToString(values.CNICNO));
                data1.Add("Health card Number:" + Convert.ToString(values.CARDNO));

            }

            Gridd = (Listview)FindViewById(Resource.Id.gridview);

            ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, data1);


            if (data1.Count() > 0)
            {
                Gridd.SetAdapter(adapter);
               // Gridd.Adapter = adapter;
                Gridd.ItemClick += Gridd_ItemClick;

            }
            else
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "No Data returned.", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }


        }
```

**Q:** How to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @Farhan, please, add some examples of what you are trying or your actual code.

Comment: Please add your code, & you can use your previous activity onResume method

Comment: I have updated the post kindly check now

Answer (score 0):

You can get the new data from DB and then call the listviewAdapter.OnNotifyPropertyChanged() in your onResume() method of your previous activity.
That would refresh your list.